# Find links that have the same nodes in common

Tags: c#

What is the fastest way of finding links that share that same exact from node and to node.

so I have a list of Links, each link has a FromNode and ToNode.
I am not sure what the fastest way would be to find those links that have common nodes. Looping around the list, and checking each link's nodes sounds like it will take a long time to find those links. What other approaches should I consider ?

picture below is attached to make things clearer.

[image]

As indecated by the picture, links 1,and 2 share B and C nodes. links 6,7 share Z and X
so the result would be those links.

Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: Start with the solution you are thinking about. Then look where you can improve it.

Comment: I usually is projects like this keep a list of all Nodes so I can enumerate through all links without having to go through all the paths.  So then the problem is solved with two for loop like a bubble sort i = 0 to N -1, j = i + 1 to N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ over your list.

Assume you have your Links class:

```
public class Links
{
    public string FromNode { get; set; }
    public string ToNode { get; set; }
}
```

Then you just simple get your result using LINQ:

```
var links = new List<Links>
            {
                new Links{FromNode = "B", ToNode = "C"},
                new Links{FromNode = "C", ToNode = "B"},
                new Links{FromNode = "A", ToNode = "D"}
            };


        var res = from a in links
                  join b in links
                  on
                  new { FromNode = a.FromNode, ToNode = a.ToNode } equals
                  new { FromNode = b.ToNode, ToNode = b.FromNode }
                  select new { a.FromNode, a.ToNode };
```